# Filter content, but do not delete the group found

Tags: regex

**I created a regex but it does not work the way I need it, and I can not create it the way I need it.**

***The REGEX:***

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

***The text***

```
[25/03/2018 11:00:28] USER 1: TESTE 1
[25/03/2018 11:12:21] USER 2: TESTE 2
[25/03/2018 11:13:21] USER 3: TESTE 3
```

***The result of this regex***

```
---------
 USER 1: TESTE 1
---------
 USER 2: TESTE 2
---------
 USER 3: TESTE 3
```

**I wanted to change the regex so that the result would be the same as the one I will show below, but I tried and can not.
Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.**

```
---------
 25/03/2018 11:00:28 | USER 1: TESTE 1
---------
 25/03/2018 11:12:21 | USER 2: TESTE 2
---------
 25/03/2018 11:13:21 | USER 3: TESTE 3
```

Comment: Replace with `$1 |`. Where (tool, programming language) is the regex used?

Comment: What language and how are you applying it? Regex doesn't do anything to your string you don't tell it to.

Comment: Also, where are the dashes coming from?

Comment: I'll use it in C #. But first I'm creating the regex

Comment: Then use `Regex.Replace(str, @"\[([^][]*)]", "$1 |")`

Comment: Have you had time to check my suggestion? It is the exact code you may use in your C# app.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the match with the backreference to Group 1 + space + `|` char.

Use

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[([^][]*)]", "$1 |");
```

See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%29%5d&i=%5b25%2f03%2f2018+11%3a00%3a28%5d+USER+1%3a+TESTE+1%0d%0a%5b25%2f03%2f2018+11%3a12%3a21%5d+USER+2%3a+TESTE+2%0d%0a%5b25%2f03%2f2018+11%3a13%3a21%5d+USER+3%3a+TESTE+3&r=%241+%7c).

The `\[([^][]*)]` regex matches `[...]` substrings with no `[` and `]` inside them, and works a bit faster than the lazy dot pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If python:

```
re.sub('\[(.*?)\]', r'\1 |', '[25/03/2018 11:00:28] USER 1: TESTE 1')
```

Returns

```
25/03/2018 11:00:28 | USER 1: TESTE 1
```